# Serializing JSON objects within a Map using Jackson 2.0

Tags: java, json, web-services, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm writing a series of Java classes to represent requests and responses in a Spring MVC web service, configured to use Jackson 2.0 annotation-based JSON handling, with the `jackson-databind` modules. Theses classes contain various fields, annotated where needed, to enable serialization and deserialization of JSON objects.

I have a POJO that contains a `Map` field, with polymorphic values. Map values can take several types, mainly `String`, other model classes, and particularly other JSON objects represented as `JsonNode`.

```
  @JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.CLASS)
  private Map<String, Object> outputValues;
```

By using the `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation, Jackson properly serializes class names in the resulting JSON, making it possible to deserialize values into the appropriate concrete type.

For instance, for a value of type `ArrayNode` (a subtype of `JsonNode`), Jackson will explicitly add the type name `"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode"`, in the resulting JSON.

```
outputValues: {
    result: [
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode",
        [
             {
                Content-Type: "application/json",
                url: "http://server.url"
             },
             {
                 Content-Type: "application/json",
                 url: "http://server.url.2"
             }
        ]
   ]
}
```

**What I wish to achieve is a special case** where, when a `JsonNode` or one of its subtypes are encountered as a map value, the JSON object is serialised **without** explicitly adding the type name into. In this example, at deserialization time, Jackson would produce `ArrayNode` when it found an unknown array structure. It would still continue to produce other polymorphic types when it encountered.

The above example would look like this:

```
outputValues: {
    result:            
        [
             {
                Content-Type: "application/json",
                url: "http://server.url"
             },
             {
                 Content-Type: "application/json",
                 url: "http://server.url.2"
             }
        ]
}
```

Comment: have you got the answer. if yes please add it as answer. I too had the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible. I added an answer of what I got so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching further, I came to the conclusion it's not possible to solve my question without overriding Jackson's serializer.

From the Jackson mailing list, I go this answer:

> You can override (de)serializer used for `JsonNode`, and that can be used to change handling of polymorphic type ids too (there is a separate `deserialize` method for case of expected type id, similarly for serializer). This might make it possible to handle your case.

I guess this is the definitive answer.

Comment: did you write the serializer?